# Is this a secure way to authenticate users?

Tags: http, security, authentication, web, authorization

I am running a small local HTTP server that allows me to manage config files via GET requests. However, this action should require a password, so I came up with the following solution:

Let's say the password is `test123`.
I hashed the password using SHA-512 and saved it to a .txt-file on my web server. When I want to get the config file `main.json`, I would send this request:

`http://192.168.178.72/config.php?mode=get&file=main&password=test123`

Is this a secure way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because as you can see, the credentials are being displayed on the url, use POST instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use https instead and a POST request to avoid printing the passphrase in the url.

As long as you use http, every connection or connection attempt could suffer under a man-in-the-middle attack.
Use of https and proper certificate pinning could avoid this